# Relative javafx Stage minimizes when moving Parent Stage

Tags: java, javafx, position, javafx-8

I got an RelativeStage which is moves if an specific parent Stage moves, but sometimes when i move the parent the relative Stage minimizes randomly.

RelativeStage:

```
package application;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RelativeStage extends Stage {

    private Stage parent;

    public RelativeStage() {
        this(new Stage());
    }
    public RelativeStage(Stage relativeTo) {
        setRelativeTo(relativeTo);
    }

    public Stage getRelativeTo() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setRelativeTo(Stage relativeTo) {
        parent = relativeTo;
        parent.xProperty().addListener((ov, o, n) -> setX(getX()-o.doubleValue()+n.doubleValue()));
        parent.yProperty().addListener((ov, o, n) -> setY(getY()-o.doubleValue()+n.doubleValue()));
    }

}
```

I thought of just maximizing it whenever the parent Stage is moved, but thats not a very satisfacting solution, because you see the minimize- and deminimize animation...